# Exclude a file while importing a dbt package

Tags: python, dbt

I've an internal dbt project and want to import it into another project as a package. While doing so.. I also want to exclude a particular file.

The internal project is there in a git repository and after adding a line in packages.yml like this -
  `- git: "https://github.com/abc/dbt_test.git" revision: "master"`

I do see it under dbt_packages folder. How do I exclude some files here?

I tried using like this -
`  - git: "https://github.com/abc/dbt_test.git"
revision: "master"
exclude: "models/folder1/folder2/data_model.sql

`
It shows the following error -
Validator Error:

```
{'git': 'https://github.com/abc/dbt_test.git', 'revision': 'main', 'exclusions': ['"models/folder1/folder2/data_model.sql']} is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to ignore a model in the package. If that's the case, dbt allows you to disable models in `dbt_project.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable a model from a package in your `dbt_project.yml`. For instance, if the model you want to disable is in the `models/` directory, you would do the following:

```yaml
models:
  <your_package>:
    <model_you_want_to_disable>:
      +enabled: false
```

You will need to address the directory structure of the project you are using as package when disabling models.

E.g. if the model you want to disable is in `models/staging/hubspot`, your `dbt_project.yml` should look like this:

```yaml
models:
  <your_package>:
    staging:
      hubspot:
        <model_you_want_to_disable>:
          +enabled: false
```

Comment: This would solve the problem, yes. Better solution would be to add the files in gitignore while pushing them to the repo itself.

Comment: Why do you think that would be a better solution? The models built through packages should not be tracked by git anyway (it's common practice to add `dbt_packages/` into your `.gitignore` file)

Comment: I;m new to dbt, many things to know.!